# Fast Method for computing 3x3 symmetric matrix spectral decomposition

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, cuda, linear-algebra

I am working on a project where I'm basically preforming PCA millions of times on sets of 20-100 points. Currently, we are using some legacy code that is using GNU's GSL linear algebra pack to do SVD on covariance matrix. This works, but is very slow.

I was wondering if there are any simple methods to do eigen decompositions on a 3x3 symmetric matrix, so that I can just put it on the GPU and let it run in parallel.

Since the matrices themselves are so small, I wasn't sure what kind of algorithm to use, because it seems like they were designed for large matrices or data sets. There's also the choice of doing a straight SVD on the data set, but I'm not sure what would be the best option.

I have to admit, I'm not stellar at Linear Algebra, especially when considering algorithm advantages. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(I'm working in C++ right now)

Comment: What specific values do you need? Do you need the eigenvalues themselves? The factorization? Solve a linear system? More detail can be helpful.

Comment: I need the 3 eigenvalues themselves, along with the last eigenvector. Thanks

Comment: You could use the analytic method, coupled with multiple precision arithmetic. It should be faster than the iterative methods based on QR, and should contain just a few branches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the characteristic polynomial works, but it tends to be somewhat numerically unstable (or at the very least inaccurate).

A standard algorithm to compute eigensystems for symmetric matrices is the QR method. For 3x3 matrices, a very slick implementation is possible by building the orthogonal transform out of rotations and representing them as a Quaternion. A (quite short!) implementation of this idea in C++, assuming you have a 3x3 matrix and a Quaternion class, can be found [here](http://www.melax.com/diag.html). The algorithm should be fairly suitable for GPU implementation because it's iterative (and thus self-correcting), can make reasonably good use of fast low-dimensional vector math primitives when they're available and uses a fairly small number of vector registers (so it allows for more active threads).

Answer (score 6):

Most methods are efficient for bigger matrices. For small ones the analytical method ist the quickest and simplest, but is in some cases inaccurate.

Joachim Kopp developed a optimized "hybrid" [method](http://www.mpi-hd.mpg.de/personalhomes/globes/3x3/) for a 3x3 symmetric matrix, which relays on the analytical mathod, but falls back to QL algorithm.

An other solution for 3x3 symmetric matrices can be found [here](http://barnesc.blogspot.com/2007/02/eigenvectors-of-3x3-symmetric-matrix.html) (symmetric tridiagonal QL algorithm).

Answer (score 5):

```
// Slightly modified version of  Stan Melax's code for 3x3 matrix diagonalization (Thanks Stan!)
// source: http://www.melax.com/diag.html?attredirects=0
void Diagonalize(const Real (&A)[3][3], Real (&Q)[3][3], Real (&D)[3][3])
{
    // A must be a symmetric matrix.
    // returns Q and D such that 
    // Diagonal matrix D = QT * A * Q;  and  A = Q*D*QT
    const int maxsteps=24;  // certainly wont need that many.
    int k0, k1, k2;
    Real o[3], m[3];
    Real q [4] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0};
    Real jr[4];
    Real sqw, sqx, sqy, sqz;
    Real tmp1, tmp2, mq;
    Real AQ[3][3];
    Real thet, sgn, t, c;
    for(int i=0;i < maxsteps;++i)
    {
        // quat to matrix
        sqx      = q[0]*q[0];
        sqy      = q[1]*q[1];
        sqz      = q[2]*q[2];
        sqw      = q[3]*q[3];
        Q[0][0]  = ( sqx - sqy - sqz + sqw);
        Q[1][1]  = (-sqx + sqy - sqz + sqw);
        Q[2][2]  = (-sqx - sqy + sqz + sqw);
        tmp1     = q[0]*q[1];
        tmp2     = q[2]*q[3];
        Q[1][0]  = 2.0 * (tmp1 + tmp2);
        Q[0][1]  = 2.0 * (tmp1 - tmp2);
        tmp1     = q[0]*q[2];
        tmp2     = q[1]*q[3];
        Q[2][0]  = 2.0 * (tmp1 - tmp2);
        Q[0][2]  = 2.0 * (tmp1 + tmp2);
        tmp1     = q[1]*q[2];
        tmp2     = q[0]*q[3];
        Q[2][1]  = 2.0 * (tmp1 + tmp2);
        Q[1][2]  = 2.0 * (tmp1 - tmp2);

        // AQ = A * Q
        AQ[0][0] = Q[0][0]*A[0][0]+Q[1][0]*A[0][1]+Q[2][0]*A[0][2];
        AQ[0][1] = Q[0][1]*A[0][0]+Q[1][1]*A[0][1]+Q[2][1]*A[0][2];
        AQ[0][2] = Q[0][2]*A[0][0]+Q[1][2]*A[0][1]+Q[2][2]*A[0][2];
        AQ[1][0] = Q[0][0]*A[0][1]+Q[1][0]*A[1][1]+Q[2][0]*A[1][2];
        AQ[1][1] = Q[0][1]*A[0][1]+Q[1][1]*A[1][1]+Q[2][1]*A[1][2];
        AQ[1][2] = Q[0][2]*A[0][1]+Q[1][2]*A[1][1]+Q[2][2]*A[1][2];
        AQ[2][0] = Q[0][0]*A[0][2]+Q[1][0]*A[1][2]+Q[2][0]*A[2][2];
        AQ[2][1] = Q[0][1]*A[0][2]+Q[1][1]*A[1][2]+Q[2][1]*A[2][2];
        AQ[2][2] = Q[0][2]*A[0][2]+Q[1][2]*A[1][2]+Q[2][2]*A[2][2];
        // D = Qt * AQ
        D[0][0] = AQ[0][0]*Q[0][0]+AQ[1][0]*Q[1][0]+AQ[2][0]*Q[2][0]; 
        D[0][1] = AQ[0][0]*Q[0][1]+AQ[1][0]*Q[1][1]+AQ[2][0]*Q[2][1]; 
        D[0][2] = AQ[0][0]*Q[0][2]+AQ[1][0]*Q[1][2]+AQ[2][0]*Q[2][2]; 
        D[1][0] = AQ[0][1]*Q[0][0]+AQ[1][1]*Q[1][0]+AQ[2][1]*Q[2][0]; 
        D[1][1] = AQ[0][1]*Q[0][1]+AQ[1][1]*Q[1][1]+AQ[2][1]*Q[2][1]; 
        D[1][2] = AQ[0][1]*Q[0][2]+AQ[1][1]*Q[1][2]+AQ[2][1]*Q[2][2]; 
        D[2][0] = AQ[0][2]*Q[0][0]+AQ[1][2]*Q[1][0]+AQ[2][2]*Q[2][0]; 
        D[2][1] = AQ[0][2]*Q[0][1]+AQ[1][2]*Q[1][1]+AQ[2][2]*Q[2][1]; 
        D[2][2] = AQ[0][2]*Q[0][2]+AQ[1][2]*Q[1][2]+AQ[2][2]*Q[2][2];
        o[0]    = D[1][2];
        o[1]    = D[0][2];
        o[2]    = D[0][1];
        m[0]    = fabs(o[0]);
        m[1]    = fabs(o[1]);
        m[2]    = fabs(o[2]);

        k0      = (m[0] > m[1] && m[0] > m[2])?0: (m[1] > m[2])? 1 : 2; // index of largest element of offdiag
        k1      = (k0+1)%3;
        k2      = (k0+2)%3;
        if (o[k0]==0.0)
        {
            break;  // diagonal already
        }
        thet    = (D[k2][k2]-D[k1][k1])/(2.0*o[k0]);
        sgn     = (thet > 0.0)?1.0:-1.0;
        thet   *= sgn; // make it positive
        t       = sgn /(thet +((thet < 1.E6)?sqrt(thet*thet+1.0):thet)) ; // sign(T)/(|T|+sqrt(T^2+1))
        c       = 1.0/sqrt(t*t+1.0); //  c= 1/(t^2+1) , t=s/c 
        if(c==1.0)
        {
            break;  // no room for improvement - reached machine precision.
        }
        jr[0 ]  = jr[1] = jr[2] = jr[3] = 0.0;
        jr[k0]  = sgn*sqrt((1.0-c)/2.0);  // using 1/2 angle identity sin(a/2) = sqrt((1-cos(a))/2)  
        jr[k0] *= -1.0; // since our quat-to-matrix convention was for v*M instead of M*v
        jr[3 ]  = sqrt(1.0f - jr[k0] * jr[k0]);
        if(jr[3]==1.0)
        {
            break; // reached limits of floating point precision
        }
        q[0]    = (q[3]*jr[0] + q[0]*jr[3] + q[1]*jr[2] - q[2]*jr[1]);
        q[1]    = (q[3]*jr[1] - q[0]*jr[2] + q[1]*jr[3] + q[2]*jr[0]);
        q[2]    = (q[3]*jr[2] + q[0]*jr[1] - q[1]*jr[0] + q[2]*jr[3]);
        q[3]    = (q[3]*jr[3] - q[0]*jr[0] - q[1]*jr[1] - q[2]*jr[2]);
        mq      = sqrt(q[0] * q[0] + q[1] * q[1] + q[2] * q[2] + q[3] * q[3]);
        q[0]   /= mq;
        q[1]   /= mq;
        q[2]   /= mq;
        q[3]   /= mq;
    }
}
```

Comment: not work for {1, 0.0001, 0},
        {0.0001, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1}  (return 45 deg)

Answer (score 0):

I am not stellar at linear algebra either but since Murphy stated that "When you don't know what you're talking about, everything is possible", it is possible that the [CULA pack might be relevant to your needs](http://www.culatools.com/features/lapack/). They do SVD and Eigenvalues decomposition

Comment: Yup I've looked at the CULA pack, but it's designed for solving large matrices by parallelizing the calculation. However, I'm looking to do many small calculations, which isn't quite what I was looking for :\ Thanks though